# Mobile Push Registrations: Sales cloud: Salesforce SDK register the connection token but after 45 days the key gets deleted

Tags: mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sdk

The connection tokens automatically gets deleted after the invterval of 45 days.
Please find the screen shot. the connection tokens gets deleted after 45 days. and for registration the new installation is required. 
[image]

Comment: Hi Priyanka, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. What is your question? Please **[edit]** your post to ask something, which will make it more clear how the community can help you.

Comment: Can you add the code showing how you register for APNS tokens? Basically AFAIC the SDK should just get re-invoked each time the token changes on Apple Side.